# Show word count after three words?

Tags: node.js, angular, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-directive

I am calling data from api in angular and it is a multiselect option what I want is if data is more than three words its should show count of remaining entries how can I do this can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to show the count? Are you asking hif the API response is 10, then the count should be 7 ?

Comment: yes something similar

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an array you can do something like this in view:

```
arrayToShow.length > 3 ? arrayToShow.length - 3 : ''
```

Or, You can use *ngIf

```
<div *ngIf="arrayToShow.length > 3 "> arrayToShow.length - 3 <>
```

If it's an object get the keys in the component and show them based on the length of the keys.

If you want to display the counts at multiple places make sure to compute them in component and reuse it.

Comment: I got solution by using {{ p.item | slice:0:3}} now what I want to do is to show count of remaining entries after first three entries

Comment: But you said you wanted to show the counts in the question? When you say the count of the remaining items - it will be a total - 3 always as given in the answer. You need to make sure if the count is lesser than 3 you don't need to show count.